# iOS issue setting height of div background image to 100% height of viewport when using skrollr-body

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, skrollr

I have a simple site with 2 sections that have a small amount of content and a background image. Before I added the id skrollr-body tag everything seemed to work fine, but now since that ID is now containing all of my content, the 100% heights are no longer working. I tried to use the 100vh property, but that didn't seem to work either. This only seems to be an issue on the iPad, and I know that is because of the way Skrollr handles scrolling on ios devices. I'm at a loss on how I can force the sections of content to be 100% of the viewport and still have Skrollr work on mobile.

Here is a simple demo of what I'm talking about

Thanks Prinzhorn for your help if you happen to read this!

[link](http://www.gdovindesigns.com/skrollr/)

Answer (score 0):

You already found the cause, solving it is skrollr unrelated and just CSS.

```
#skrollr-body {
    height:300%;
}

section {
    height:33.3333%;
}
```

Edit: This approach is more general and should work the same as without skrollr-body

```
#skrollr-body {
    height:100%;
    overflow:visible;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that way kind of not efficient? How would I know how big the height of the skollr body should be? It' easy if each section is 100% tall, but if that were the case then using the absolute way would make more sense vs the relative method.

Comment: If it's not a percentage of the body height, then you don't need this trick anyway.

Comment: So maybe I am missing something. If I had 3 sections. The first section has a logo and a background image. The background img should be the height of the viewport. The 2nd section has an image and some text and is more then 100% height of the view port. And the 3rd section is like the first, background image with some content that can fit inside the viewport at 100%. Since I don't know the height of that 2nd section how can I set scrollr to a % of height, because the height of sections 1 and 3 will be different then section 2. Does that make sense?

Comment: This also only seems to effect that iOS, on desktop everything is fine.

Comment: I updated the answer with another solution, which should work for those cases.